# Shiny UI user text input disconnects from cursor while typing if you are not fast enough

Tags: r, shiny

For my user interface I am having people select variables to combine. The issue is for the first column (see blue circle in image below) when they are entering text if they are not fast enough it disconnects somehow and you have to re-click the box to keep typing. Is there a way to fix this?

A cut off time if needed is okay for it disconnecting but whatever it is currently doing is just way too short.

```
combinedoptions <- c( "Select Channel : Campaign", "Select Channel : Digital", "Select Channel : YouTube", "Select Channel : Social",
                      "X_Media_Banner : Digital Only,Unexposed", "X_Media_Banner : YouTube Only,Unexposed", "X_Media_Banner : Social Only,Unexposed", 
                      "X_Media_Banner : Digital+Social,Unexposed", "X_Media_Banner : Unexposed", "X_Media_Banner : Digital+YouTube,Unexposed", 
                      "X_Media_Banner : Social+YouTube,Unexposed", "X_Media_Banner : Digital+Social+YouTube,Unexposed", "Demo_Age : 18-34", 
                      "Demo_Age : 35-44", "Demo_Age : 45-64", "Demo_Age : 65+", "Demo_Gender : Female", "Demo_Gender : Male", 
                      "Demo_Employment : Employed Full-Time", "Demo_Employment : Employed Part-Time", "Demo_Education : College",
                      "Demo_Education : Graduate Degree", "Demo_Education : HS or less", "Demo_Education : No Answer", 
                      "Demo_Education : Some College", "Demo_Income : Under $35k", "Demo_Income : $35k to $60k",
                      "Demo_Income : $60k to $100k", "Demo_Income : $100k+", "Demo_Income : No Answer" )


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Produce custom groupings for new slides. What goes on one slide is determined by the name in first column so make them the same if you want it on the same slide."),
  
  # Column Headers
  fluidRow(
    column(1, h4(HTML("<b><font color='red'>PPT Slide Name REQUIRED</font></b>"))),
    column(1, h4("")),
    column(1, h4(HTML("<b><font color='red'>Select Channel Here REQUIRED</font></b>"))),
    column(1, h4("")),
    column(1, h4("")),
    column(1, h4("")),
    column(1, h4("")),
    column(1, actionButton("addRowButton", "Add Row +")),
    column(1, actionButton("saveButton", "Save and Close"))
  ),
  
  # Dynamic Rows
  uiOutput("customRows"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  rows <- reactiveVal(1)
  row_values <- reactiveVal(list(list("", "", "", "", "", "", "")))
  row_text <- reactiveVal(list(""))
  
  observeEvent(input$addRowButton, {
    current_values <- row_values()
    last_row <- current_values[[length(current_values)]]
    current_values <- c(current_values, list(last_row))
    row_values(current_values)
    
    current_text <- row_text()
    last_text <- current_text[[length(current_text)]]
    current_text <- c(current_text, list(last_text))
    row_text(current_text)
    
    rows(length(current_values))
  })
  
  observe({
    rows_count <- rows()
    for (i in 1:rows_count) {
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("dropdown", i, "_1")]], {
        row_values_list <- row_values()
        row_values_list[[i]][[1]] <- input[[paste0("dropdown", i, "_1")]]
        row_values(row_values_list)
      })
      
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("dropdown", i, "_2")]], {
        row_values_list <- row_values()
        row_values_list[[i]][[2]] <- input[[paste0("dropdown", i, "_2")]]
        row_values(row_values_list)
      })
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("dropdown", i, "_3")]], {
        row_values_list <- row_values()
        row_values_list[[i]][[3]] <- input[[paste0("dropdown", i, "_3")]]
        row_values(row_values_list)
      })
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("dropdown", i, "_4")]], {
        row_values_list <- row_values()
        row_values_list[[i]][[4]] <- input[[paste0("dropdown", i, "_4")]]
        row_values(row_values_list)
      })
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("dropdown", i, "_5")]], {
        row_values_list <- row_values()
        row_values_list[[i]][[5]] <- input[[paste0("dropdown", i, "_5")]]
        row_values(row_values_list)
      })
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("dropdown", i, "_6")]], {
        row_values_list <- row_values()
        row_values_list[[i]][[6]] <- input[[paste0("dropdown", i, "_6")]]
        row_values(row_values_list)
      })
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("dropdown", i, "_7")]], {
        row_values_list <- row_values()
        row_values_list[[i]][[7]] <- input[[paste0("dropdown", i, "_7")]]
        row_values(row_values_list)
      })
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("textbox", i)]], {
        row_text_list <- row_text()
        row_text_list[[i]] <- input[[paste0("textbox", i)]]
        row_text(row_text_list)
      })
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$saveButton, {
    global_values <- list(
      row_values = row_values(),
      row_text = row_text()
    )
    assign("global_values", global_values, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  })
  
  
  output$customRows <- renderUI({
    rows_count <- rows()
    rows_list <- lapply(1:rows_count, function(i) {
      current_values <- row_values()
      selected_row_values <- current_values[[i]]
      
      current_text <- row_text()
      selected_text <- current_text[[i]]
      
      row_ui <- list(
        fluidRow(
          column(1, textInput(paste0("textbox", i), label = "", value = selected_text)),
          column(1, h4(paste0("Custom Group ", i))),
          column(1, selectInput(paste0("dropdown", i, "_1"), paste0("Custom Group ", i), choices = c("", combinedoptions), selected = selected_row_values[[1]])),
          column(1, selectInput(paste0("dropdown", i, "_2"), paste0("Custom Group ", i), choices = c("", combinedoptions), selected = selected_row_values[[2]])),
          column(1, selectInput(paste0("dropdown", i, "_3"), paste0("Custom Group ", i), choices = c("", combinedoptions), selected = selected_row_values[[3]])),
          column(1, selectInput(paste0("dropdown", i, "_4"), paste0("Custom Group ", i), choices = c("", combinedoptions), selected = selected_row_values[[4]])),
          column(1, selectInput(paste0("dropdown", i, "_5"), paste0("Custom Group ", i), choices = c("", combinedoptions), selected = selected_row_values[[5]])),
          column(1, selectInput(paste0("dropdown", i, "_6"), paste0("Custom Group ", i), choices = c("", combinedoptions), selected = selected_row_values[[6]])),
          column(1, selectInput(paste0("dropdown", i, "_7"), paste0("Custom Group ", i), choices = c("", combinedoptions), selected = selected_row_values[[7]]))
        ),
        fluidRow(
          column(12, hr())
        )
      )
      
      return(row_ui)
    })
    do.call(tagList, rows_list)
    
  })
  
  
  
  observeEvent(input$saveButton, {
    stopApp()
  })
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    stopApp()
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: The reason its happening is because everytime you enter something into the box, the `renderUI` is envoked again you create brand new `customRows`.

Comment: As implied by @PorkChop the issue is a [circular-reference](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-dynamic.html#circular-references). Unfortunately your code is far away from beeing minimal - so it's hard to help. On a side note: do you really need those nested observers?

Comment: @ismirsehregal and PorkChop thanks so much for the input. I understand what you mean by the circular reference however I cannot figure out how to change my code to fix this. I am pretty new to shiny so any help would be appreciated.